# The FINISH button on GnuCash Account Reconciliation is greyed out

Tags: accounting, gnucash

This is my first attempt at using GnuCash to reconcile checking account. I've checked the transactions that appear on statement and the green check appears in the 'R' Column.

According to GnuCash Help manual, since this is my first reconciliation my Starting Balance is zero. However, the ending balance matches the statement balance and my reconciliation appears complete. What should I do next to enable the finish button?

I'm using GnuCash 2.4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From GnuCash user's group](http://gnucash.1415818.n4.nabble.com/Finish-reconciling-td3848391.html#a3848414)

```
The greyed out means that you still have a difference, meaning the 
reconcile isn't finished.  So you need to track down that difference:
```